# Fill in the blank using suitable option :

Tags: calculation-puzzle

The question appeared in one of the aptitude tests **:**

> **$8$** **:** **$24$** **:** **:**  ___ **:** **$32$**

**Options are :**

**A.** **$10$**

**B. $8$**

**C. $5$**

**D. $6$**

Comment: This isn't an alphametic; please check tag wikis before using them.

Comment: @Deusovi I know that it's "verbal arithmetic" but when I'm selcting it after submitting its shows "alphametic." Some bug maybe. Please don't downvote it.

Comment: "verbal arithmetic" is a synonym of "alphametic". It automatically changes to the primary tag. In any case, this isn't verbal arithmetic either.

Comment: And I downvoted because this is a low-quality question.

Comment: Please do not change the tag back to alphametic, this is not one.

Comment: Downvoted because this is a poor question from a poor aptitude test. Please feel free to post good questions. I'm sure you can probably think up better ones yourself. People on this site are more than happy to upvote questions that show some creativity and will offer advice, if requested, on how to improve any puzzles you create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> D. 6

Here's the reasoning:

> The first number is equal to the product of the digits in the second number. 8 = 2x4 and 6 = 3x2.

Answer (score 5):

If the "$::$" is meant to be there I guess this is
"$24$ is to $8$ as $32$ is to $?$"
In which case the answer is

> **D.** $6$

Because

> $2\times 4=8$ and $3\times 2=6$

Answer (score 4):

One possible option

> 6

since

> 2 * 4 = 8, and 3 * 2 = 6

Comment: I ninja'd you :)

Comment: Que sera, sera :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different answer:

> B

Reasoning:

> $x = x_{n}x_{n-1}\dots x_1$ 
>  $f(x) = \sum i\times x_i$ 
>  
>  
>  $f(24) = 2\times 2 + 1 \times4 = 8$ 
>  $f(32) = 2\times 3 + 1 \times 2 = 8$

Answer (score 1):

Answer is

> 6

Because

> **8 = 2 * 4 and 6 = 3 * 2**

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

> 10

For one thing,

> Obviously; seeing as 8 produces 24, the number that produces a number greater than 24 must be greater than 8

but, more formally,

> $n : 4(n-2)$. Easy as fitting a straight line between 2 points. Which could as easily justify any of the other options. Which is why questions of this genre are subjective.